# Is an empty string `[]byte("")` serialized as `\0`

Tags: string, go, embedded, i2c

Our code base is Go and C++. I'm a C++ programmer, so I can sort of follow Go, but I don't understand it well.

We are an embedded shop and the Go folks are serializing a string and sending it on an I2C buffer. It appears an empty Go string is appended to the I2C transaction as `\0`, instead of  "nothing".

Everything I've seen in Go documentation has only described how to test for it (i.e. `str == ""` or `len(str) > 0`), but doesn't appear to describe how it is serialized.

As a C++ programmer, `\0` makes sense, because it is the null terminator for strings or even simply `NULL`, which would make sense to store in a variable. Can someone please confirm or deny this?

Comment: I appreciate the link, but it does not speak as to how the value of an empty string is serialized. Also, I don't understand why this was down voted. Please provide feedback in the comments, so I can improve the question.

Comment: @velkor Please post an answer with this, so I can give you the check mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Go Language does not specify how Go values are serialized. The encoders in the Go standard library serialize empty strings in different ways. The [gob](https://godoc.org/encoding/gob) encoder omits empty strings. The [JSON](https://godoc.org/encoding/json) encoder writes empty strings as "" (unless told to omit the empty string).

In memory string values do not have a null terminator.